# Determine whether the following set is ideal in the ring $R$ or not

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ be ideal in $R$, and $a \in R$.

1. Is $J_a = \{x \in R \mid ax \in I \}$ be ideal in $R$ ?
2. Is $I \subset J_a$? Explain.

${}$

My attempt:

1. Since $0 = a0 \in I, 0 \in J_a$ and then $J_a \ne \emptyset$. Let $m,n \in J_a$. Then,
   $am, an \in I$. Now, $a(m-n) = am - an \in I$. Hence, $m-n \in J_a$.
   Now, for any $r \in R$, we have
   $(am)r = a(mr) \in I$. Hence, $mr \in J_a$. But, on the other hand, we have
   $r(am) = (ra)m = (ar)m = a(rm) \in I$ i.e. $rm \in J_a$ iff $R$ is an abelian ring. Hence, $J_a$ is not ideal in $R$, but it be the right ideal in $R$.
2. Since for any $x \in I$ i.e. $ax \in I$, then $x \in J_a$ i.e. $I \subset J_a$.

Am I true?

Comment: (2) is better written as "For any $x \in I$, $ax \in I$, so $I \subset J_a$". What you wrote doesn't show the desired conclusion.

Comment: @mizh What do you mean about doesnt show .... ?

Comment: @user795084 It is indeed correct that as long as $I$ is a *right* ideal than the *right* quotient of sets $(I \colon a)_{\mathrm{d}}$ is also a right ideal. If $I$ is furthermore a *bilateral* ideal than the inclusion $I \subseteq (I \colon a)_{\mathrm{d}}$ is also valid.

Comment: okey, noted sir